# pyenv can't find/use pip (pip3 is found though)

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Trying to migrate from `virtualenv` to `venv` (python3). Also would like to use `pyenv` to manage multiple versions of python 3.x on my Mac.

Following [this](https://medium.com/@henriquebastos/the-definitive-guide-to-setup-my-python-workspace-628d68552e14) article, I installed `pyenv`, `pyenv-virtualenv` and `pyenv-virtualenvwrapper` via `brew` without a problem:

```
brew install pyenv
brew install pyenv-virtualenv
brew install pyenv-virtualenvwrapper
```

Modified my `.zsh_env.sh` in `~/.config/zsh_env.sh` like so:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/workspace

eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Installed two Python versions:

```
➜  ~ pyenv versions
  system
  2.7.15
* 3.7.2 (set by /Users/ugur/.python-version)
```

Trying to create a virtual environment, but I get a complaint that `pip` is missing:

```
➜  ~ pyenv virtualenv 3.7.2 jupyter3
pyenv: pip: command not found

The `pip' command exists in these Python versions:
  2.7.15
```

If I try to run `pip` in my terminal, I get the same error:

```
➜  ~ pip
pyenv: pip: command not found

The `pip' command exists in these Python versions:
  2.7.15
```

`pip3` seems to be installed/seen though:

```
➜  ~ pip3

Usage:
  pip3 <command> [options]

Commands:
  install                     Install packages.
  download                    Download packages.
... (omitted)
```

How can I use `pyenv` in combination with `venv` to manage environments and python versions?

## Edit

Tried to install `pip` via `pip3` like so (without success):

```
➜  ~ pip3 install pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (18.1)
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
➜  ~ pip install --upgrade pip
pyenv: pip: command not found

The `pip' command exists in these Python versions:
  2.7.15
```

## Edit 2

Not even aliasing pip helped:

```
➜  ~ alias pip=pip3
➜  ~ pyenv virtualenv 3.7.2 jupyter3
pyenv: pip: command not found

The `pip' command exists in these Python versions:
  2.7.15
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a similink as such

```sh
ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
```

Now calling `pip` will actually be `pip3`.

Note : This doenst work if python was installed with brew, as the directory isnt `/usr/bin`, as pointed out in below comment.

Comment: this doesnt work if your python is installed via brew - the 3.8 and 3.9 brew pythons dont have pip but rather pip3, and wont be installed in /usr/bin

Comment: Thank you @tesch1 what directory it is installed when via brew?